# rspec failing "Missing host to link to!..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I'm currently getting the following error:

```
 1) Organization.invite_user should create a new user for a specific orgs initial user
     Failure/Error: organization.invite_user(second_email)
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
     # ./app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_devise_mailer_reset_password_instructions_html_erb___4480543240081585515_70131221479860'
     # ./app/models/organization.rb:34:in `invite_user'
     # ./spec/models/organization_spec.rb:24:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Anyone know what could be happening here in rspec?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in your config/environments/test.rb file, you should provide the following configuration:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'www.example.com' }
```

for links to be generated by ActionMailer

Answer (score 1):

The error seems pretty self explanatory: you need to provide more information to your mailer initializer so that it knows how to actually render the links.

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

If you don't do that, the links would have to be relatives, which makes no sense when talking about links in emails.

Comment: can you give me an example of how you would do this? I'm pretty new to rails